# JavaFX: TableView, ObservableList and updating TableColumn

Tags: java, javafx-8

I have the following problem, I'm trying to make a gui where you input numbers and they show up in a `LineChart` and a `TableView`. The numbers on the `xAxis` and the left column are weeks and the numbers on the `yAxis` and the right column are balances. It's supposed to update the balance if I input the same week twice. Everything works out fine but the `TableView`. It adds but doesn't update the values.

```
public class LineChartSample extends Application {
    static final BorderPane ROOT = new BorderPane();
    static final HBox TABCHA = new HBox();
    static final GridPane TEXLAB = new GridPane();
    static final Label WOCHE = new Label("Woche: ");
    static final TextField WOCHET = new TextField();
    static final Label KONTOSTAND = new Label("Kontostand: ");
    static final TextField KONTOSTANDT = new TextField();
    static final Button HINZAEND = new Button("Hinzufügen / Ändern");
    static final Button LOESCHEN = new Button("Löschen");
    static final Label TEXT = new Label();
    static final TableView<XYChart.Data<Number, Number>> TABLE = new TableView<XYChart.Data<Number, Number>>();

    public void start(Stage stage) {
        NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();
        xAxis.setLabel("Woche");
        NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
        yAxis.setLabel("Kontostand");
        LineChart<Number, Number> lineChart = new LineChart<Number, Number>(xAxis, yAxis);
        lineChart.setTitle("Kontostände 2014");

        XYChart.Series<Number, Number> series1 = new XYChart.Series<Number, Number>();
        series1.setName("Konto 1");
        lineChart.getData().add(series1);

        TableColumn<XYChart.Data<Number, Number>, Number> woche = new TableColumn<XYChart.Data<Number,Number>, Number>("Woche");
        TableColumn<XYChart.Data<Number, Number>, Number> kontostand = new TableColumn<XYChart.Data<Number,Number>, Number>("Kontostand");

        woche.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<XYChart.Data<Number, Number>, Number>("xValue"));
        kontostand.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<XYChart.Data<Number, Number>, Number>("yValue"));

        woche.setSortType(TableColumn.SortType.ASCENDING);

        TABLE.setItems(series1.getData());
        TABLE.getColumns().add(woche);
        TABLE.getColumns().add(kontostand);
        TABLE.getSortOrder().add(woche);
        TABCHA.getChildren().addAll(TABLE, lineChart);

        TEXLAB.add(WOCHE, 0, 0);
        TEXLAB.add(WOCHET, 1, 0);
        TEXLAB.add(KONTOSTAND, 2, 0);
        TEXLAB.add(KONTOSTANDT, 3, 0);
        TEXLAB.add(HINZAEND,4,0);
        TEXLAB.add(LOESCHEN,0,1);
        TEXLAB.add(TEXT, 0, 2, 4, 1);

        HINZAEND.setOnAction(e -> {
                try {
                    TEXT.setText("");
                    int index = 0;
                    boolean vorhanden = false;
                    for (Data<Number, Number> data: series1.getData()) {
                        if(data.getXValue() == (Number)Integer.parseInt(WOCHET.getText())) {
                            data.setYValue(Double.parseDouble(KONTOSTANDT.getText()));
                            series1.getData().get(index).setYValue(Double.parseDouble(KONTOSTANDT.getText()));;
                            vorhanden = true;
                        }
                        index += 1;
                        System.out.println(index);
                    } 
                    if (!vorhanden) {
                        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<Number, Number>(Integer.parseInt(WOCHET.getText()), Double.parseDouble(KONTOSTANDT.getText())));
                    }
                    if (ROOT.getTop() != TABCHA) {
                        ROOT.setTop(TABCHA);
                    }
                    TABLE.sort();
                    System.out.println(series1.getData());
                } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                    TEXT.setText("Falsche Eingabe");
                }
            });

        LOESCHEN.setOnAction(e -> {
                TEXT.setText("");
                try {
                    for (Data<Number, Number> data: series1.getData()) {
                        if(data == TABLE.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem()) {
                            lineChart.getData().get(0).getData().remove(data);
                        }
                        if(series1.getData().isEmpty()) {
                            ROOT.getChildren().remove(TABCHA);
                        } 
                    }
                    if (TABLE.getSelectionModel().isEmpty()){
                        TEXT.setText("Keine Elemente selektiert");
                    }
                    if(series1.getData().isEmpty()) {
                        TEXT.setText("Keine Elemente zum Löschen vorhanden!");
                        ROOT.getChildren().remove(TABCHA);
                    } 

                }catch (ConcurrentModificationException ex){

                }
            });

        ROOT.setBottom(TEXLAB);
        Scene scene = new Scene(ROOT, 800, 600);
        stage.setTitle("Liniendiagramm");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: It works for me in java 1.8.0.25 .  Maybe try `XValue` for the `propertyValueFactory`.  I noticed the data subclass didn't follow convention in naming it, it's `XValueProperty`.  The get and set are normal so it should work anyway.  Also, use the diamond operator, it will be easier to read the code.

Comment: Thanks @brian. Changing it to `XValue` and `YValue` did the trick. Changed also to the diamond operator and it looks better.